# Multiple Mixins with same events in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mixins, superclass, super

I would like to include multiple mixins within a view in Ember.js and more than one of the mixins and/or the view uses a same event (e.g. `willInsertElement`). I'm running Ember 1.4.0-beta.5.

I understand that the event in each mixin will be overridden by the view. However, I have read that it is possible to use the same event hook in the mixin and view, or multiple mixins included in the same view, by calling `this._super();` at the start of the mixin's aforementioned event method. However, I have not been able to successfully make this happen. My question is, thus, how can I write logic within the same event hook in a view and mixin (or multiple mixins included in the same view) so that all the logic within each occurrence of the event hook will be called.

Here is an example:

```
App.StatsView = Em.View.extend(
    App.DateFormatting, {

    willInsertElement: function() {
        // Some view-specific logic I want to call here
    },
});

App.DateFormatting = Em.Mixin.create({

    willInsertElement: function() {
        this._super(); // This doesn't work.
        // Some mixin logic I want to call here
    },
});
```

N.B. One approach here might be to not use a mixin and extend a view instead (because willInsertElement is specific to Em.View), but that isn't maintainable in our apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the different functions you're using are not dependent on each other, it's the best solution to not override the `willInsertElement` hook, but to tell the function to be raised when the event/hook gets called.

Like:

```
App.StatsView = Em.View.extend(App.DateFormatting, {
  someSpecificFunction: function () {
    console.log('beer me');
  }.on('willInsertElement')
});

App.DateFormatting = Em.Mixin.create({
  dateFormattingFunction: function () {
    console.log('beer you');
  }.on('willInsertElement')
});
```